# Photoshop CC 2017 + Python

Tags: python, com, photoshop, comtypes

I have the exact same problem than the one described in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25401567/8320072), with **Photoshop CC 2017**, **python 2.7.13**, **comtypes 1.1.3**, **windows 7** (all 64-bits)
Trying to call a Photoshop method via python + comtypes raises a TypeError saying that the object is not callable:

```
from comtypes.client import CreateObject
psApp = CreateObject("Photoshop.Application.110") # edited to match photoshop CC 2017
#Create a new document- this is where it bombs out!
psApp.Documents.Add(1024, 1024, 72, 'new_source_texture', 2, 1, 1)

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    psApp.Documents.Add(1024, 1024, 72, 'new_source_texture', 2, 1, 1)
TypeError: '_Dispatch' object is not callable
```

...accessing it as if it were a property actually invoke the method with default args:

```
psApp.Documents.Add  #without explicit call
```

Has anyone encountered or solved this issue?
thanks!

Paul

Comment: According to [python comtypes dispatch object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861258/python-comtypes-dispatch-object-is-not-callable) this seems to be a 32 vs 64-bit issue with COM handling?

Comment: I've tried this morning with an older Photoshop (CS6), same platform / python / comtypes, and it works. It joins comments I've found elsewhere saying that the problem appeared with CC 2015 (sorry, no source)

Comment: It actually works in CC 2017 if CC 2014 (or previous version I presume) is also installed.